# What variables (besides HOME) determine from where terraform expects to find the git key for modules with github as a source

Tags: jenkins, terraform

What command line option and environment variables control how terraform finds keys for downloading modules from git?

When using terraform modules from a git repo I'm running into problems when I execute the plan via jenkins build server.

I'm using modules with a source like this:

```
source = "git@github.com:mygroup/myrepo.git//mymodule"
```

Which results in the following as the private / deploy key isn't in the jenkins user's home/.ssh dir

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I can use a **WithEnv(["HOME=dir"])** clause and build up a .ssh directory but I think there must be a more elegant **withCredential** + command line option to handle this scenario.

Do you know of a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your terraform steps in [`sshagent`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/):

```
sshagent(['my-credential-id']) {
  sh 'terraform init'
  // etc.
}
```

Replace `my-credential-id` with the ID of the credential containing your deploy private key.

Comment: Oh that's awesome.  I wish I'd found that prior to implementing my own.  Silly me.  Thanks Jay. https://serverfault.com/questions/927712/git-clone-hangs-during-clone-when-using-sshpass