# git clone hangs during clone when using sshpass

Tags: ssh, jenkins, github, terraform

Has anyone found sshpass works to set a phassphrase for ssh or git clones?

I have a github repo with a deploy key and a passphrase

This results in prompt for passphrase as expected and clone upon manual key-in of it

```
git clone git@github:me/myrepo.git
```

This results in a hang

```
sshpass -p "secret" -v git clone git@github:me/myrepo.git
```

This seems to happen because the search string will never match the actual string but there seems no way to alter the search string.

```
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
SSHPASS read: Enter passphrase for key '/home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you cannot use sshpass to provide a passphrase, only a password in user/password vs private key ssh.

Assuming you are using Jenkins - and since you are me, you are.  we can resolve the problem following this strategy:

1. obtain key and passphrase
2. setup ssh wrapper to use the keyfile automatically
3. setup ssh-agent to enable provisioning of passphrase and automatic handout upon request by ssh
4. use expect to install passphrase in ssh-agent

thanks to @jayhendren for turning me on to the [ssh-agent plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)

**The Jenkins pipeline groovy code**

```
/**
 * generate stand in executable for ssh to ensure we use the correct id and do not look in home's .sshdir
 * @return path to shell script wrapper for ssh
 */
def getSshWrapper(def keyPath) {
    def wrapper = "${pwd()}/ssh"
    writeFile file: wrapper, text: """#!/usr/bin/env sh
/bin/ssh -i ${keyPath} \$*"""
    sh "chmod 700 ${wrapper}"
    return wrapper
}

/**
 * Enable ssh and git to use a deploy key with a passphrase
 * @param credentialId jenkins id of private key / passphrase
 * @param closure actions to perform
 * @return result of actions
 */
def withDeployKey(def credentialId, closure) {
    def result

    // Start ssh agent and add key
    def helperFilesDir = './build/helperFiles'
    def envSettings = ["PATH=${helperFilesDir}:${env.PATH}"]
        withEnv(envSettings) {
            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: credentialId,
                    passphraseVariable: 'PASSPHRASE',
                    keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE_PATH')]) {

                println "Setup Ssh Wrapper to use credentials key"
                dir(helperFilesDir) {
                    getSshWrapper(KEY_FILE_PATH)
                }

                // Run closure
                println "run closure"
                sshagent(credentials: [credentialId]) {
                    result = closure()
                }
            }
        }
    return result
}
```

**Example**

```
withDeployKey('my-deploy-key') {
   sh "git clone git@github:me/myrepo.git'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the `passphrase` prompt to the `sshpass` using `-P` switch and it will work like a charm, for example whenever I enter `git pull` the prompt asking for my passphrase would be:

```bash
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sinux/.ssh/id_ed25519':
```

Therefore I'd have to use `sshpass` like the below:

```
sshpass -P "Enter passphrase for key '/home/sinux/.ssh/id_ed25519':" -p <passphrase> git pull
```

I've tested this method and used it widely in my scripts, hope it works for you too.